# spring junit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit

I have a maven spring project (latest version) and I want to write some junit tests (latest version).

The issue I have is that my spring beans are autowired, and when I call them from junit test, I get null pointer exceptions, as spring doesn't autowire them.

How can I load the context so that things are autowired?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you studied [Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html) chapter in Spring reference documentation? Here is an example you should start with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

    @Resource
    private FooService fooService;

    // class body...
}
```

If you are in `com.example.MyTest` in `/src/test/java`, you will need `/src/test/resources/com/example/MyTest-context.xml` - but the exceptions will show you the way.

Comment: :-) Our code snippets our suspiciously similar, I smell the same reference we both used ;-).

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html, no wonder :)

Comment: thanks, this works, but im using autowired. (which was the issue because I wasnt before). 
Anyway the main issue is I don't know how to get my applicationContext.xml from WEB-INF into the required root...

Comment: this solved the problem:
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <additionalClasspathElements>
     <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</additionalClasspathElement>
      </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>

Comment: @MassiveBoisson: I have added the maven-surefire plugin to pom.xml, but it's not working?

Answer (score 12):

This is a possibility:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "/applicationContext.xml"
// in the root of the classpath
@ContextConfiguration({"/applicationContext.xml"})
public class MyTest {
// class body...
}
```

Usually it's a good idea though to have a test-applicationContext for your test infrastructure.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` on your test classes, and use `@Resource` (or `@Autowired`) on the field in your test class that contains the bean. You should consider having a special test context Spring configuration that uses stubs so that your tests are genuine unit tests, and don't rely on the whole application context.