# spring annotation NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

```
@Component
public class AnnotationTest extends TestCase{
    ServiceTest serviceTest;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    public  void setServiceTest(ServiceTest serviceTest) {
        this.serviceTest = serviceTest;
    }
    public void testAnnotation () {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"/com/test/spring/ioc/beans.xml"});
        serviceTest.annotationTest("testName", "testPassword");
    }
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.spring.ioc.AnnotationTest.invokeIoC(AnnotationTest.java:16)
    at com.test.spring.ioc.AnnotationTest.main(AnnotationTest.java:13)
```

service class:

```
@Service
public class ServiceTestImpl implements ServiceTest{
    @Autowired
    AnnotationDAO annotationDAO;
    public List<String> annotationTest(String name, String pssword) {       
        return annotationDAO.annotationTest(name, pssword);
    }
}
```

DAO class:

```
@Repository("AnnotationDAO")
public class AnnotationDAOImpl implements AnnotationDAO{

    public List<String> annotationTest(String name, String pssword) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Test 1");
        list.add("Test 2");
        return list;
    }
}
```

beans.xml:

```
<bean id="service" class="com.test.spring.ioc.service.ServiceTestImpl"/>    
    <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.spring" />
```

how can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

it was giving warning msg:

```
    WARNING: Autowired annotation is not supported on static methods: public static void 
com.test.spring.ioc.AnnotationTest.setServiceTest(com.test.spring.ioc.service.ServiceTest)
```

i moved to junit test instead of java main method as shown above by adding @Component( i am not sure this is required).
Now i am getting new error as:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'annotationTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
com.test.spring.ioc.service.ServiceTest com.test.spring.ioc.AnnotationTest.serviceTest; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
unique bean of type [com.test.spring.ioc.service.ServiceTest] is defined: expected single 
matching bean but found 2: [service, serviceTestImpl]   at     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProce   ssPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
```

Comment: I hadn't realised that this was going into unit tests, this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546871/spring-junit-testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you are defining the same bean twice:

Once explicitly:

```
<bean id="service" class="com.test.spring.ioc.service.ServiceTestImpl"/>
```

And once through Component Scanning:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.spring" />
```

Get rid of one of them and it will work.

BTW: you don't need to instantiate the container yourself when testing, just use the [Spring TestContext Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "/applicationContext.xml"
// and "/applicationContext-test.xml"
// in the root of the classpath
@ContextConfiguration({"/applicationContext.xml",
                       "/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class MyTest {
    // class body...
}
```

And of course, with JUnit 4.x you should no longer extend from TestCase, but use annotated methods instead:

```
@Test
public void testAnnotation () {
    serviceTest.annotationTest("testName", "testPassword");
}
```

Comment: it throws java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods. but i have method of annotationTest

Comment: if i extends junit TestCase or reomve it, i am getting No runnable methods

Comment: @ksaim so then you apparently use Junit 3.x. You need to upgrade to a newer version!

Comment: @kasim oh wait, you don't have a `@Test` annotation on your method, do you?

Comment: thank you so much. finally solved. I have learned spring junit4.8 also ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `AnnotationTest` class is not instantiated by spring, so Spring never has a chance to inject the serviceTest dependency:

You can either explicitly get you bean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
             new String[]{"/com/test/spring/ioc/beans.xml"});
    serviceTest = ctx.getBean(ServiceTest.class);
    invokeIoC();
}
```

or you could tell annotate your `AnnotationTest` class with `@Component` so that an instance will be created by the `component-scan`.  Note, though I think that would be a bit of a hack as you'll be instantiating an `AnnotationTest` object and never use it, so I'd do away with the autowiring in the main and use `getBean`...

EDIT:

In order to do the autowiring of a static field, you'd also have to fool spring into thinking that serviceTest is not actually static (again, I don't think that's a good idea):

```
@Component
public class AnnotationTest {
    static ServiceTest serviceTest;

    ...

    @Autowired
    public void setServiceTest(ServiceTest serviceTest) {
        AnnotationTest.serviceTest = serviceTest;
    }
}
```